# Two way binding not working in AngularJS form in Service Now platform

Tags: angularjs, servicenow, two-way-binding

I'm working at a form on the **ServiceNow** platform, using **AngularJS**. It seems like something quite simple like two way binding is not working.

Here's a simplified snippet of my html:

```
<form name="vulnerabilityForm" ng-submit="addVulnerability(newVulnerability, newSeverity)">
  <div class="col-sm-10"> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vulnerability" ng-model="newVulnerability" required> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <select ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in severityOptions" class="form-control" id="severity" ng-model="newSeverity" required> 
      <option value="">Select Severity</option> 
    </select> 
  </div>
</form>
```

And the client script:

```
$scope.vulnerabilities = [];

$scope.newVulnerability = '';
$scope.newSeverity = null;

$scope.addVulnerability = function(newVulnerability, newSeverity) {  
    $scope.vulnerabilities.push({
            description: newVulnerability,
            severity: newSeverity
        });

   // reset input fields
    $scope.newVulnerability = "";
    $scope.newSeverity = "";
    $scope.vulnerabilityForm.$setPristine();
    $scope.vulnerabilityForm.$setUntouched();
};
```

**What I am trying to achieve**:

1. Update and pass the values of `newVulnerability` and `newSeverity`  to the client script via `ng-submit`
2. reset the form upon submission (hence emptying the text `input` and resetting the `select`)

**Problems**:

1. It's my understanding that `ng-submit="addVulnerability()"` should just submit the values, which are updated via the `ng-model` directive which enables the two way binding.
   However, the values won't update for some reason.
   I solved this by explicitly passing the values in the submit, like so - `ng-submit="addVulnerability(newVulnerability, newSeverity)"`. This seems to be working, but not via two way binding.
2. Resetting the form does not work - again, shouldn't resetting the variables to empty strings automatically update the UI as well?

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of SN are you running?

Comment: @NickParsons thanks for the reply. We are using this version: 

Build name: Tokyo;
Build date: 02-28-2023_1844;
Build tag: glide-tokyo-07-08-2022__patch7-02-16-2023;

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue in a PDI? I tried with a CDN version of angularjs but couldn't reproduce

Comment: I tried to reproduce in a [tokyo PDI](https://dev147059.service-now.com/sp_config?id=widget_editor&sys_id=d03b9076972221107e9bbcb3f153af15) but it works as expected there (user: admin, password: EA-kK$0xeK9g)

Comment: I can confirm everything works as expected in your PDI - thanks for this. Unfortunately it still won't work in my SN  (I copied and pasted your exact code). I am not an expert in AngularJS, I am not sure what else could cause the behaviour to be different...

Comment: hm, interesting. Do you see any errors in your browser console at all? When you reload your page with the widget?

Comment: Nope, no errors related to the form or the variables - yes it's really weird. Will investigate more and will update this question if I find out what's missing. thanks for your help!